# New iTunes Connect - New Version issue (missing screenshot)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I uploaded a iPhone/iPad build from Xcode as a resub by mistake and subbed it. Then, I noticed straight away that this was incorrect as I received an email from Apple mentioning a missing screenshot.

Now, iTunes Connect has just changed to a new UI and I have uploaded an iPhone only build. However, it keeps telling me I'm missing a screenshot and that I cannot "select the build." The build shows within "pre-release," but I cannot get rid of the other build and select the new one, before "submitting for review."

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To REMOVE (- button):

[image]

To Add 1 (+ button):

[image]

To Add 2 (select):

[image]

Comment: For me + button is missing